# Averaging multi level data to one single level data using CDO

Tags: merge, average, cdo-climate

So I have 3D data of sea currents velocity. I want to calculate/averaging data from z=28 to z=26 so I can display the value in spatial (lat1 lat2 lon1 lon2). I don't think 'merge' command is the solution, because I want to calculate the average, not only put them all in one file. How can I create those vertical data from different levels into a single level netcdf file using CDO?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Its not not clear what you are trying do. Are you trying to the calculations from data in multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a .nc with 8 levels.
First select the range of levels from the 8 levels by : (**cdo select,level=min_lev,max_lev ifile ofile**). E.g cdo select,level=1000,850 cloud_height.nc cloud_height_1000_850.nc. The above selected 2 levels.

Secondly, to get the vertical average / vertical mean, you : (**cdo vertmean ifile ofile**). E.g cdo vertmean cloud_height_1000_850.nc cloud_vertical_mean.nc